# exec() and my stupidity

Tags: java, linux

I just wanted to share my stupidity and how I used up all the disk space, about 90 GB with a couple of lines of code.

All I wanted to do was to list out all the files in a directory (including the sub-directory) containing a set of string and save the information in a file. I thought find would help, I tested that as well....

```
find . -exec grep -i "TEXT_TO_FIND" '{}' \; -print >TEXT_TO_FIND.txt
```

However, I need to pick up the string to search dynamically and build the command string dynamically, after figuring out the right way of building the command string , I ran my program. I thought exec() would wait 
for a signal from the Operating system that the task has finished. I think it does not. Even if it did, my program will never complete because it would also search in the files which I have been creating by redirecting, 
the output and thus grep was running indefinitely until all the disk space was utilized.

I just want to confirm that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` does not wait for any signal from OS.

Comment: Inexperience is not the same as stupidity. Technically, this is not a question and will likely be closed though.

Comment: `find -exec` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` do different things.

Comment: As an attempt to save this, you can reformulate your question to be an actual question, and answer it with your new-found insight on the matter. Hopefully others might contribute with what they know and thus this could be a useful resource for others to not make the same mistake, which I believe is what your goal was when you "asked" this "question" :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, Rob, posdef. Yes, it was not a question, but I was annoyed with myself and wanted to share with folks at stackoverflow. My intention was to share my experience and hoped that folks would come up correct solutions, ideas for people like me. So that we can learn and improve.

Comment: You may want to note that a Java class library method that exposes `exec(3)` is not the same as a base GNU utility that is most likely written in C or Perl and calls directly into Glibc. A Java wrapper could do all sorts of things that are completely different from that of the native function. And to make it even more complicated, there is no `exec(3)` function in the API: It's a family of `exec`-like functions that all do subtly different things.

Comment: @dRv: That was a nice thing to do, but the way that SO is structured, it's only helpful if it is a real question about a problem you have, or a real *question* about something you are curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` does not wait for any signal from the OS. If you want to pause your program until the subordinate program completes, try this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitfor();
```